# How to get pipeline information for a Repo in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api

I would like to know the pipeline for a given Repo, I cannot see any direct way to get this information, Is there any way to get this?

Comment: There is no way to get information like this. You can get information what repos are used by given pipeline. But not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the data from the build validation policy of the branch name, if there is a pipeline mentioned over there. If it is not tagged there, you can't get it.